# Create dynamic ranges and calculate mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I would like to create an additional column with averages based on column A, using dynamic ranges.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
test = {'A' : [100, 120, 70, 300, 190, 70, 300, 190, 70],
        'B' : [80, 50, 64, 288, 172, 64, 288, 172, 64],
        'C' : ['NO', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'YES'],
        'D' : [0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)

     A      B      C      D    
0   100    80     NO      0
1   120    50     NO      1
2    70    64    YES      0
3   300   288     NO      3
4   190   172    YES      2
5    70    64    YES      2
6   300   288     NO      3
7   190   172    YES      1
8    70    64    YES      4
```

When item in column `C` is `YES` get average value from dynamic range in column `A`  by using value in column `D` as starting row index and row index of current row `-1` as highest row index.

Below is the outcome I am seeking to achieve.

```
     A      B      C      D    Dyn_Ave    
0   100    80     NO      0     NaN
1   120    50     NO      1     NaN
2    70    64    YES      0     110
3   300   288     NO      3     NaN
4   190   172    YES      2     185
5    70    64    YES      2     187
6   300   288     NO      3     NaN
7   190   172    YES      1     175
8    70    64    YES      4     188
```

My attempt at creating the column has lead me to a np.where approach, although I am coming across the following error - TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

```
df['Dyn_Ave'] = np.where(df['C'] == 'YES', df['A'].iloc[df['D']:df.loc['C'][-1]].mean(), np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
s = df['A'].cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)

df['Dyn_Ave'] = np.where(df['C'] == 'YES', 
                         (s - s.reindex(df['D']).values) / (np.arange(len(df)) - df['D']),           
                         np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C  D     Dyn_Ave
0  100   80   NO  0         NaN
1  120   50   NO  1         NaN
2   70   64  YES  0  110.000000
3  300  288   NO  3         NaN
4  190  172  YES  2  185.000000
5   70   64  YES  2  186.666667
6  300  288   NO  3         NaN
7  190  172  YES  1  175.000000
8   70   64  YES  4  187.500000
```

---

**Explanation**: Let's first forget about `C=='YES'` for a moment and paying attention to dynamic average. The average from row `df['D']` to row `j-1` can be seen as

```
(cumsum[j-1] - cumsum[df['D']-1])/(j-df['D'])
```

or:

```
(cumsum.shift()[j] - cumsum.shift()[df['D']) / (j-df['D'])
```

That's why we first calculate the cumsum, then shift it:

```
s = df['A'].cumsum().shift(fill_value=0)
```

To get the cumsum at `df['D']`, we use reindex and pass the underlying numpy array for subtraction:

```
(s - s.reindex(df['D']).values)
```

The number of rows can be easily seen as:

```
(np.arange(len(df)) - df['D'])
```

The last part is just filling in where `C=='YES'`, just as you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: your bitesize explanations for each component helped me immensely with understanding the concepts as well as solving my issue perfectly. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.apply`, but it will be slower than `np.where`.

```py
df['Dyn_Ave'] = df[df.C == 'YES'].apply(lambda x: np.round(df.A.loc[x.D:x.name-1].mean()) ,axis=1)
df
```

Out:

```
     A    B    C  D  Dyn_Ave
0  100   80   NO  0      NaN
1  120   50   NO  1      NaN
2   70   64  YES  0    110.0
3  300  288   NO  3      NaN
4  190  172  YES  2    185.0
5   70   64  YES  2    187.0
6  300  288   NO  3      NaN
7  190  172  YES  1    175.0
8   70   64  YES  4    188.0
```

Comment: thanks for this. However, I am trying to maintain as much speed as possible within my project, which is why the `np.where` version is much more suited

Comment: No problem, @QuangHoang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65364280/14277722) is not only (probably much) faster, but a really fascinating insight into the structure of your question.